# hibernate query find by criteria from other table

Tags: java, hibernate

This was the original query :

```
public List<Ride> listRides(Long userId) {
        List<Ride> ride = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
            ride = getHibernateTemplate()
                    .find("from Ride v where v.userId = ? AND finished = true AND isDeleted = false order by startTime DESC",
                            userId);

        return ride.size() > 0 ? ride : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
```

Now I need to check if the ride id is allowed to show and for that purpose i need to check in another table .
Tables constructions is :

Ride table :

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hd_routes_id_seq'::regclass),
ride_name character varying(40),
category_id bigint,
etc....
```

RidePrivacy table :

```
id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('hd_rides_privacy_id_seq'::regclass),
ride_id bigint,
is_visible boolean
```

I added this to the Ride class:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "RidesPrivacy", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id") , inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ride_id") )
```

and rework dao implementation to this :

```
public List<Ride> listRides(Long userId) {
        List<Ride> ride = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
            StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
            query.append("from Ride v where v.userId = ? AND finished = true");
            query.append("AND Ride.RidesPrivacy.isVisible= true ");

            query.append("AND isDeleted = false order by startTime DESC");

            ride = getHibernateTemplate().find(query.toString(), userId);


        return ride.size() > 0 ? ride : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }
```

But when I execute it it returns me :

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: Invalid path: 'null.RidesPrivacy.isVisible'
```

Comment: try v.RidesPrivacy.isVisible

Comment: how is is_visible mapped?

Comment: In RidesPrivacy class: 
@Column(name = "is_visible")
 private Boolean isVisible;

Comment: when i try with v. i get:

could not resolve property: RidesPrivacy

Comment: I think you should add a RidePrivacy field (or property) in class Ride